# purpose of 'and' in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

Can someone define me the exact purpose of the `and` keyword in assembly? I have provided a code here can someone explain me what the `and` does in this code? By the way the `and` is located somewhere under `begin` just for you to locate it easily.

```
code segment
assume cs:code;ds:code
org 100h

begin:

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg1
int 21h

mov ah,01h ;ask user
int 21h
and al,01h
jz EVENn
mov ah, 09 ;display string
mov dx, offset oddmsg
int 21h
jmp ENDd

EVENn:

mov ah, 09 ;display string
mov dx, offset evenmsg
int 21h

ENDd:
int 20h

msg1:db 'enter a number: $'
evenmsg:db 0ah,0dh, 'EVEN $'
oddmsg:db 0ah,0dh, 'ODD$'

code ends
end begin
```

Answer (score 1):

The `and` opreator does a logical and operation.

In this case it's used to mask out a single bit in a value. If you for example get the value `6Dh` in `al` (the character `m` read from STDIN), the operation leaves only the least significant bit:

```
6Dh  01101101
01h  00000001
--------------- and
     00000001
```

An even character code gives the result `00h`, and an odd character code gives the result `01h`.

Comment: Ok I understand all except for the 6dh and "the character m read from STDIN". I hope you can make things simpler for me as I'm just new to assembly. Thank you!

Comment: @DwayneRadar: The `int 21h` method `01h` is used to read a character from STDIN, and the character code is returned in `al`.

Comment: @DwayneRadar: It's the standard input stream of the console.